# In a situational deontic logic, is a permission with no alternative degenerate?

Tags: situational-ethics, deontic-logic

Relativize issues of permissibility to situations, so that we would say things like, "In situation *S*, it is permitted that *P*." Let **PM***A* = "It is permitted that *A*," and **OB***A* = "It is obligated that *A*." Now, intuitively, but per our occurrent "situationism"(?):

- **PM***A* ∧ **PM***B* = **OB**(*A* ∨ *B*)

... seeing as we are imagining that, per our occurrent *S*, no *C* besides *A* and *B* is permitted, so *C*'s are *forbidden* (**FR***C*).

So an example of degeneracy from the literature (or Wikipedia, at any rate) is a *degenerate continuum* = the singleton set of a single point. By analogy, for situationism, would the equation **PM***A* = **OB***A* be degenerate whensofar as *A* is the only thing permitted in some *S*?